# $f$ is bijective, show that $h(x)=\left(f(x); g(x)\right) \rm{\ is\ bijective\ } \iff G $ is Singleton

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-verification, alternative-proof

> Let E, F and G be three sets ($E\neq 0;F\neq 0,G\neq 0 ) $ Let $h$ defined by :
>   $$\begin{align} h \ \colon\ E & \to F\times G\\ x & \mapsto h(x)=\biggl(f(x);g(x)\biggr). \end{align}$$
>   with $\begin{align} f \ \colon\  E & \to F \\ x & \mapsto f(x). \end{align}$
>   and $ \begin{align} g \ \colon\  E & \to G \\ x & \mapsto g(x). \end{align}$

Suppose that $f$ is bijective. show that :

$h \rm{\ is\ bijective\ } \iff G $ is Singleton

Indeed;

- Show that
  $$ h \rm{\ is\ bijective\ } \implies G \rm{\ is\ Singleton } $$

*Proof by contradiction:*

suppose that G contains at least two elements $(a,b)\in G^2$ such that $a\neq b$
Let $y\in F$ and since $f$ is bijective then $\exists ! x\in E $ such that $f(x)=y$, since $h$ is bijective and $(y,a)\in F\times G$ then $\exists ! x  \in E$ such that $h(x)=(y;a)$ the same thing for $(y;b)\in F\times G$ then $\exists ! x  \in E$ such that $h(x)=(y;b)$ thus $g(x)=a=b$ which is contradictory .

- Show that
  $$ G \rm{\ is\ Singleton }  \implies h \rm{\ is\ bijective\ } $$
  Let $G=\{a \}$ then $\forall x \in E,\quad h(x)=\left(f(x);a \right)$
- i'm stuck here how can i prove that h is bijective

Comment: To prove that it is bijective, prove that it is surjective and that it is injective. Each separate step is easy enough.

Comment: what about $$\forall (y;z)\in F\times G \ \exists !\ x \in E\ \rm{\ such\ that \ } h(x)=(y,z) $$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general a map $k:X\to Y$ is bijective if and only if it has an inverse . This is actually a map $l:Y\to X$ such that $l\circ k=\text{id}_X$ and $k\circ l=\text{id}_Y$.

This map $l$ is unique, bijective and is denoted as $k^{-1}$. Its (unique) inverse is the map $k$.

---

Function $f:E\to F$ in your question is bijective, so has an inverse $f^{-1}:F\to E$.

Then the map $h:E\to F\times\{a\}$ prescribed by $x\mapsto\langle f(x),a\rangle$ has an inverse in the map $F\times\{a\}\to E$ that is prescribed by $\langle y,a\rangle\mapsto f^{-1}(y)$.

Comment: now i can see, Thanks so much

Comment: You are welcome.

Comment: what is called that theorem ?

Comment: As far as I know there is no name for it. It is a special case for the more general notion of "isomorphism". These are invertible (i.e. having an inverse) morphisms in groups, rings, modules, etc. When it concerns just sets then isomorphisms are exactly the bijections. It is very handsome to know that a bijection is exactly a map that has an inverse.

Answer (score 1):

Let’s start by getting an intuition for what’s going on. Since $f$ is a bijection, $F$ is intuitively just $E$ by another name: for $x\in E$ we can think of $f(x)$ as just a sort of alias for $x$. Thus, the special case in which $E=F$ and $f$ is the identity function should be representative of all possibilities.

In that special case $h(x)=\langle x,g(x)\rangle$ for each $x\in E$. Clearly $h$ is injective: if $x_0\ne x_1$, then

$$h(x_0)=\langle x_0,g(x_0)\rangle\ne\langle x_1,g(x_1)\rangle=h(x_1)\;.$$

Now fix $x_0\in E$, suppose that there is some $y\in G\setminus\{g(x_0)\}$, and let $x\in E$ be arbitrary. Then $h(x)=\langle x,g(x)\rangle$, and either $x\ne x_0$, in which case $h(x)\ne\langle x_0,y\rangle$, or $x=x_0$, in which case $h(x)=\langle x_0,g(x_0)\rangle\ne\langle x_0,y\rangle$. Thus, $\langle x_0,y\rangle$ is not in the range of $h$, and $h$ is not surjective (and hence not bijective). On the other hand, if $G=\{g(x_0)\}$, then $g(x)=g(x_0)$ for all $x\in E$, and the function $h$ is simply $h(x)=\langle x,g(x_0)\rangle$ for all $x\in E$. But then for each $\langle x,y\rangle\in F\times G=E\times G$ we have $y=g(x_0)$ and hence $\langle x,y\rangle=\langle x,g(x_0)\rangle=h(x)$, so that $h$ is surjective (and hence a bijection).

Now see if you can make the relatively slight modification needed to replace the identity map with an arbitrary bijection $f:E\to F$. It may help to note that if $i:E\to E$ is the identity map, when I initially wrote that in the special case we have $h(x)=\langle x,g(x)\rangle$, I could just as well have written $h(x)=\langle i(x),g(x)\rangle$. If you go through and find where a plain $x$ or $x_0$ is being thought of as $i(x)$ or $i(x_0)$ — i.e., where it’s being thought of as a member of the codomain of $i$ rather than as a member of the domain — you can pretty much just replace $i$ by $f$.

Comment: @Educ: You’re welcome.